# How to write an output number as a comma

Tags: jquery

When I enter a number with a comma, The number output does not change.
The following code is written with jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
input: <input type="text" id="location-address" name="kalaPrice" class="input-formse price idnumprice" value="100000"><br><br>
out: <input id="location-name" type="text" name="kalaPrice" class="" value="100000" /> $
  <script>
      $(function() {
          $('#location-address').keyup(function() {
              var value = $(this).val();
              $('#location-name').val(function (index,value) {
                return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "");
              });
          }).keyup();
      });
  </script>
  <script>
      $('input.idnumprice').keyup(function (event) {
      if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
        $(this).val(function (index, value) {
        return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        });
      });
  </script>
```

Look at the photo below:

[image: Embedded image]

Please advise!

Comment: well your output is reading its own value!!!! `$('#location-name').val(function (index,value) { <----`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you use `value` twice in the same function;

```
$(function() {
  $('#location-address').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#location-name').val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "");
    });
  }).keyup();
});
```

Should be:

```
$(function() {
  $('#location-address').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#location-name').val(function(index) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "");
    });
  }).keyup();
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#location-address').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#location-name').val(function(index) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "");
    });
  }).keyup();
});

$('input.idnumprice').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
input: <input type="text" id="location-address" name="kalaPrice" class="input-formse price idnumprice" value="100000"><br><br> out: <input id="location-name" type="text" name="kalaPrice" class="" value="100000" /> $
```

Comment: makes no sense to use val() with a function when you are not using the function